# Index Match Lookup

Tags: excel

I have two excel spreadsheets; one containing field with a social security number, name, date of birth, etc and the other containing the same info but the date of birth is left blank.  What formula would I use to match the social on workbook one to a social on workbook two and return the date of birth for that record from workbook one to workbook two?

[image: Workbook One]

[image: Workbook Two]

Comment: Either VLOOKUP() or INDEX/MATCH().  Google will show you how to use them.

Comment: I tend to recommend [Index/Match](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=index%20match%20excel) as it can be a little more robust.  However, if you only need to return the DOB (which is right of the data you'll use to look it up), a [`Vlookup()`](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/11/01/vlookup-excel-formula/)  should work as well without any headaches, and tends to be a little easier to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the exact context right, but here's how you can use an Index/Match formula to get this.

In your DOL Life Census worksheet cell J189, put this formula:

`=Index('BAS Census'!H:H,match(A189&B189,'BAS Census'!A:A&'BAS Census'!B:B,0))`

and enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+DELETE</kbd>.

(I recommend having both sheets open, and just entering manually, selecting those ranges with your mouse.)  What this does is return a value from an Index (column), based a which row.  So, it's going to return some value from "BAS Census column H", based on what row A189 ("Broussard") and B189 ("James") are in BAS Census Columns A and B, respectively.

I used First and Last names to get a match, as I assume there may be two people with the same first or last name.  We could be even more specific by checking for First, Last, and SS#.  You'd just add `&C189` to the first part of the `Match()` formula, and add the range you expect the socials to be in (`&'BAS Census'!C:C`) to the end of the second part.

Comment: Do it off the ssn number and it does not need to be an array.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Thanks for pointing that out. I left in the array part because I think he'll probably be asking that sooner than later.  OP, if you just use the SS# (which I absentmindedly forgot *will* be unique), then just do `=Index('BAS Census'!H:H,match(C189,'BAS Census'!C:C,0))` and use `ENTER`.